# Login issue in laravel 9.x with filament

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have just installed the filament admin panel package with my fresh laravel project. If I run the project by "php artisan serve" the application logins successfully. But when I try to run the project using localhost/myproject/admin/login it runs fully but it doses not logins to the application and returns to the same login page after clicking on the login page with a question mark "?" in the url.

It also does not show any kind of errors. My env debug is set to true already.

I have tried to make it live on a server but on a live server, it is also not working. Does anybody have any idea how to diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try to inspect your filament login page, and look in the network section. If there is a problem with livewire, then my suggestion is to change the config > livewire.php section on the line that says: from 'asset_url' => null to 'asset_url' => 'https://your-domain/public'.

Your problem is the same as mine, and that way my problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things i did based on one answer from here and one from a liveware fix.

First if there isn't a liveware config file create one:

```
php artisan livewire:publish --config
```

then add

```
    'asset_url' => 'appname/public/livewire/livewire.js',
```

Second on RouteServiceProvider add

```
Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
        $url =  'appname/public/livewire/update';
        return Route::post($url, $handle);
    });
```

the above answer for change in .env didn't work for me i had to do this.

btw, i'm using filament 3 and liveware 3.

Comment: That was a perfect solution for me, thank you!

Comment: it works, thanks. **Noob hints for the app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php file edit:** 
1) `Livewire::setUpdateRoute...` piece of code has to be placed inside the boot() function; 
2) don't forget to add `use Livewire;` on top.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone needs it, this is what works for me **Filament v3** with **Livewire v3**,

In My case, I have 2 apps at `/` and `/admin`, and set my server config accordingly, so for /admin fixes,

First I change `APP_URL` in `.env` from
`APP_URL=http://localhost` to `APP_URL=/admin`,

This pretty much solves the `http://localhost/livewire/livewire.js` issue and now I am getting the correct `http://localhost/admin/livewire/livewire.js.`

Then, there was still a livewire update route '/livewire/update' issue so I created a `.env` variable `LIVEWIRE_UPDATE_URL` and set it `/admin`.

`LIVEWIRE_UPDATE_URL=/admin`

For **Livewire v3**, there is a function to set the update route so I used that in `RouteServiceProvider` boot section like below,

```
if (app()->environment() === "production") {
    Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
        $url = env('LIVEWIRE_UPDATE_URL') . '/livewire/update';
        return Route::post($url, $handle);
    });
}
```

here I only needed this function in my production hence the if(production) statement.

```
> Note: **php artisan optimize** will through an error, seems laravel bug or something, so i just use **php artisan route:clear** instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation at https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/users#authorizing-access-to-the-admin-panel

Just need to configure it correctly. If you run it locally via php artisan serve you should be able to login

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You already created an user?, according to documentation

> php artisan make:filament-user

Answer (score 0):

Updated instruction on new versions for those still running into the error.

For Laravel 10 and Filament 3.x you can simply add login routing via the config file.

After running the `make:filament-panel <panel name>` command, edit the config file for your new panel.  Usually found in App\Providers\Filament\

With in the config file after the `return $panel...`, add the following line: `->login()`. I added mine after the `->path('')`

Here is a sample of one of my panels

> ```
>      ...
>      return $panel
>        ->default()
>        ->brandName("Site Name")
>        ->id('panel')
>        ->path('')
>        ->login()
>        ...
> ```

Save and try again.  I also added the `->default()` option, and removed the default option from the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and installing php-zip extension worked for me.

Run this command :

> composer require filament/filament:"^3.2" -W

(or whatever is the latest version at the time you see this)

Running this command gave me following error;

> - openspout/openspout v4.23.0 requires ext-zip * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.

**Warning :** in my case it was caused by the missing `zip` extension, in your case it might be different, so run the previous code and see if you get any error. Because you might need to install something other than zip extension, look under Problem 1 to see what extension is missing.

I ran the following command to install php-zip

> sudo apt install php-zip

Then I ran the first command again;

> composer require filament/filament:"^3.2" -W

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem like this:
Create a `/livewire` directory in the `public/`
and copy the `livewire.js`
from `/vendor/livewire/livewire/dist/`